# Problems inserting into database after server upgraded PHP and SQL

Tags: .htaccess, mariadb, php-7, php-7.2

If I don't explain this issue properly, please say and I'll edit it to suit.

I have a program called 'LiveAgent' which relies heavily on SQL insertion and retrieval - which was working untl my server upgraded the PHP from 7.0 to 7.2, and the SQL from 10.1 to 10.2.17_MariaDB. I've been told the .htaccess needs changing so the software can communicate with the server. I'm very confused. The software shows all entries until the 22nd, when the server was upgraded (UK2). Since then you can't submit anything into it.

The htaccess file is below. As is the code for adding an 'appointment'.

---

HTACCESS

```
# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews

#http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
  </IfModule>

  ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

---

AJAX:

```
    if($ajax['1'] == 'add_new_appointment'){
        include 'files/add_new_appointment.php'; 
    }
```

---

ADD NEW APPOINTMENT

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
    <div class="modal-body">

    <?php // ------------- ERROR -----------------
        foreach ($notification_msg as &$notification) { ?>
        <div class="alert <?php echo $notification['type'] ?>"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong><?php echo $notification['h4'] ?> </strong> <?php echo $notification['msg'] ?></div>
    <?php } // ------------- ERROR ----------------- ?>


                <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="<?php echo $ajax['0'] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="create_appointment" value="true">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Find Customer *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select name="customer" id="customer-single" style="width:100%" required> 
                            <option value="">Select a customer</option>
                            <?php  foreach(customer_array($ajax['0']) as $customer){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $customer['id'] ?>"><?php echo $customer['business_name'] ?> - <?php echo $customer['first_name'] ?> <?php echo $customer['last_name'] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    If your customer is not listed you can add them <a href="https://[domain]/customer/new/">here</a>.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select name="category" id="category-single" style="width:100%" required> 
                            <option value="">Select a category</option>
                            <?php  foreach(category_array($ajax['0']) as $category){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $category['id'] ?>"><?php echo $category['name'] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="date" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label">Time *</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input class="form-control timepicker" type="text" name="start_time" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <label class="control-label">To *</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input class="form-control timepicker" type="text" name="end_time" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Booked By *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select name="booked_by" id="agent-single"  style="width:100%" required> 
                            <?php  foreach (agent_array($ajax['0']) as $agent){ ?>
                            <option <?php if($agent['id'] == get_agent_from_session($ajax['0'], 'id')){echo 'selected';} ?> value="<?php echo $agent['id'] ?>"><?php echo $agent['first_name'] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Booked for *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select name="booked_for[]" id="agent-multi"  multiple="multiple" style="width:100%" required> 
                            <?php foreach (agent_array($ajax['0']) as $agent){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $agent['id'] ?>"><?php echo $agent['first_name'] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Notes</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="notes"> </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

DATABASE CONNECTION

```
// arrays 
$notification_msg = array();
$bank_holidays = array();

// connect to db
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhostname;dbname=db", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    //$notification_msg[] = array(type=>'alert-success', h4=>'Success', msg=>'Connected to database');
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $notification_msg[] = array(type=>'alert-success', h4=>'', msg=>$e->getMessage());
    }
```

PHP/SQL Code:

```
if($_POST['create_appointment']){ 
        $customer_id   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['customer'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $category_id   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['category'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $date       = htmlspecialchars($_POST['date'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $start_time = htmlspecialchars($_POST['start_time'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $end_time   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['end_time'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $booked_by  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['booked_by'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $booked_for =  post_array_to_explode($_POST['booked_for']);
        $notes      = htmlspecialchars($_POST['notes'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $session_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['session_id'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $time       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $agent_id   = get_agent_from_session($session_id, 'id');

        $start_date = $date.' '.$start_time;
        $end_date = $date.' '.$end_time;

        $start_date = format_datetime_mysql($start_date);
        $end_date = format_datetime_mysql($end_date);

        $insert = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO calendar(start_date, end_date, notes, category_id, customer_id, added_by, booked_by, booked_for, date_added) VALUES ('$start_date', '$end_date', '$notes', '$category_id', '$customer_id', '$agent_id', '$booked_by', '$booked_for', '$time')");
            if($insert){
                $notification_msg[] = array(type=>'alert-success', h4=>'Success!', msg=>'Appointment Created');
                push_browser_notify('New appointment booked', format_date($start_date).' - '.get_customer_json('business_name', $customer_id).' ('.get_customer_json('first_name', $customer_id).' '.get_customer_json('last_name', $customer_id).') ', '');     

                header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

        }else{
            $notification_msg[] = array(type=>'alert-warning', h4=>'Warning!', msg=>'Appointment NOT Created');
        }
}
```

Comment: "I've been told the .htaccess needs changing so the software can communicate with the server." - If that's true, you might just have to change "ea-php70" to "ea-php72". And make sure that ea-php72 is installed using yum. (It looks like here 'ea' is 'EasyApache', which I've never come across before.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'm going to try that.

"<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>" do I also need to change the  .php7 to .php72 as well?

It's not a VPS though, so I can't use yum - however the server upgraded this themselves.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'd check if you have ea-php72 installed with `rpm -q ea-php72`, which you can run even if you're not root. I'd guess the server logs are in /var/log/httpd/error_log if you have access to that.

Comment: "however the server upgraded this themselves" - so someone else upgraded your system and broke your app? Then they should support you in fixing this.

Comment: Oh sorry I'd assumed the PHP wasn't being run. If it is, and you're just getting the 'Appointment NOT Created' error then you probably need to see what's returned by [`$dbh->errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php). That said, it looks like you're substituting user-supplied strings into a SQL statement which is generally a bad idea: you should use a prepared statement and arguments instead, else you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: They sent out an email a month ago apparently, in order to fix but no-one has had access to the email.

The ea-php72 command doesn't work, as it doesn't recognise rpm.

I put the code for insertion within the database above.

For reference, the app works on GoDaddys server (which uses a more compatible PHP). But it has to be on the current one.

Comment: OK. If you are getting 'Appointment NOT Created' then please see if there's an error returned in $dbh->errorInfo() (e.g. append `.print_r($dbh->errorInfo(),true)` to the 'Appointment NOT Created' string). And if you have access to the Apache error logs then please check that for anything relevant too, e.g. failure to load a PHP module or mysql client library dependency on start-up. You should also ask them to send you another copy of the email, directly to you.

Comment: I seem to be getting errors like this, when nothing has actually changed in code?

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: calendar-only-show-business-type in /agent/inc/post.php on line 842
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: disable_domain in /agent/inc/post.php on line 851
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: enable_domain in /agent/inc/post.php on line 862

Comment: Hey,

I keep getting the below errors. Bear in mind - the PHP has upgraded from 7.0 to 7.2 and SQL upgraded to MariaDB 10.2.17 with STRICT mode enabled. I cannot switch this off.

Errors:

Comment: I don't expect the undefined index stuff has changed, it's just that it was ignored before, and PHP returned null or undefined from operations that it's warning about, and carried on OK. And since it says 'Notice' I'd guess that's just a warning and not the actual problem here either. I still think that if you are getting the 'Appointment NOT Created' warning on your UI then you are attempting the database insert and failing, so unless there's a reason in the logs that the DB connection isn't going to work then you need to see what the error was from the failed insert.

Comment: Is there a different syntax to this?

I keep getting the below errors. Bear in mind - the PHP has upgraded from 7.0 to 7.2 and SQL upgraded to MariaDB 10.2.17 with STRICT mode enabled. I cannot switch this off.

Errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: calendar_id in /ajax/ajax.php on line 105

The code is:

    if($_POST['id']){
      $ajax = explode(":", $_POST['id']);
 }elseif($_GET['json']){
  $calendar_id = $_GET['json'];
 
Is there a syntax error here?